# Filter grouped data by partial string specified in another column

Tags: r, filter, group-by

I want to filter grouped data using either a.) a partial string specified in another column, or if easier, b.) a partial string which I specify in the code.

I have the following data frame:

```
  df <- structure(list(
  sen = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
  trial = c("standard", "standard", "standard", "standard", "standard", "silence", "silence", "silence", "silence", "silence", "deviant", "deviant", "deviant", "deviant", "deviant","standard", "standard", "standard", "standard", "standard", "silence", "silence", "silence", "silence", "silence", "deviant", "deviant", "deviant", "deviant", "deviant"),
  ppt = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
  ia_label = c("The_TW1", "cow_TW2", "jumped_TW3", "the_TW4", "gate_TW5","The_TW1", "cow_TW2", "jumped_TW3", "the_TW4", "gate_TW5", "The_TW1", "cow_TW2", "jumped_TW3", "the_TW4", "gate_TW5", "The_TW1", "cow_TW2", "jumped_TW3", "the_TW4", "gate_TW5","The_TW1", "cow_TW2", "jumped_TW3", "the_TW4", "gate_TW5", "The_TW1", "cow_TW2", "jumped_TW3", "the_TW4", "gate_TW5"), 
  target_pos = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "TW3", "TW3", "TW3", "TW3", "TW3", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "TW4", "TW4", "TW4", "TW4", "TW4")),
  .Names = c("sen","trial","ppt","ia_label","target_pos"),
  row.names = c(NA, -30L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

| sen | trial | ppt | ia_label | target_pos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | standard | 1 | The_TW1 | 0 |
| 1 | standard | 1 | cow_TW2 | 0 |
| 1 | standard | 1 | jumped_TW3 | 0 |
| 1 | standard | 1 | the_TW4 | 0 |
| 1 | standard | 1 | gate_TW5 | 0 |
| 1 | silence | 2 | The_TW1 | 0 |
| 1 | silence | 2 | cow_TW2 | 0 |
| 1 | silence | 2 | jumped_TW3 | 0 |
| 1 | silence | 2 | the_TW4 | 0 |
| 1 | silence | 2 | gate_TW5 | 0 |
| 1 | deviant | 3 | The_TW1 | TW3 |
| 1 | deviant | 3 | cow_TW2 | TW3 |
| 1 | deviant | 3 | jumped_TW3 | TW3 |
| 1 | deviant | 3 | the_TW4 | TW3 |
| 1 | deviant | 3 | gate_TW5 | TW3 |
| 2 | standard | 1 | The_TW1 | 0 |
| 2 | standard | 1 | cow_TW2 | 0 |
| 2 | standard | 1 | jumped_TW3 | 0 |
| 2 | standard | 1 | the_TW4 | 0 |
| 2 | standard | 1 | gate_TW5 | 0 |
| 2 | silence | 2 | The_TW1 | 0 |
| 2 | silence | 2 | cow_TW2 | 0 |
| 2 | silence | 2 | jumped_TW3 | 0 |
| 2 | silence | 2 | the_TW4 | 0 |
| 2 | silence | 2 | gate_TW5 | 0 |
| 2 | deviant | 3 | The_TW1 | TW4 |
| 2 | deviant | 3 | cow_TW2 | TW4 |
| 2 | deviant | 3 | jumped_TW3 | TW4 |
| 2 | deviant | 3 | the_TW4 | TW4 |
| 2 | deviant | 3 | gate_TW5 | TW4 |

and I want to filter the data frame by 'ia_label's that contain the string specified in the target_pos for deviant conditions (either tw3 or tw4) - but I want to group this by 'sen' - so for all of sen = 1, I want to keep only the rows with ia_label containing _TW3, and for sen = 2 I want to keep only the rows with ia_label containing _TW4:

| sen | trial | ppt | ia_label | target_pos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | standard | 1 | jumped_TW3 | 0 |
| 1 | silence | 2 | jumped_TW3 | 0 |
| 1 | deviant | 3 | jumped_TW3 | TW3 |
| 2 | standard | 1 | the_TW4 | 0 |
| 2 | silence | 2 | the_TW4 | 0 |
| 2 | deviant | 3 | the_TW4 | TW4 |

I only have a small number of different strings that I need to filter by, so I don't mind running this manually by specifying the partial string I want to filter 'ia_label' by, if it isn't possible to filter each group by the partial string specified within the 'target_pos' column.

I have tried using the following code using group_by, filter and grepl but I receive the error below:

```
library(dplyr)
Df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(sen) %>%
  filter(df, grepl("TW3",ia_label))
```

Output:

*Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 15 or 1, not size 30.
i Input `..1` is `df`.
i The error occurred in group 1: sen = 1.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.*

Comment: The error is because you are both piping `df` into `filter` and specifying it inside `filter`. It works if you change to `df %>%   group_by(sen) %>%  filter(grepl("TW3", ia_label))` (changing `filter(df, grepl(` to `filter(grepl(`.)

Comment: @GregorThomas ah thank you so much! I just couldn't work out what I was doing wrong. This is perfect :)

Comment: @GregorThomas - sorry to add another query to this - could you please explain what/where x is (in reference to us specifying that x = ia_label) - and could you also explain why we use pattern = first (given that we don't want to take the first row, only the row that matches the text specified in target_pos?)

Comment: Look at the `?grepl` help page, its arguments are `pattern` for the pattern to search for and `x` the character vector to search in. So `x = ia_label` means we are searching through `ia_label` looking for a match. The pattern we want to match is, in your words, *"the string specified in the `target_pos` for deviant conditions"*, which in code is `target_pos[trial == "deviant"]`. But we have a possible problem: the `pattern` argument must be length-1, but if there is more than 1 row in the group with `trial == "deviant"` then the pattern will be more than 1, so I take the `first()` just in case

Comment: @GregorThomas that's great - thank you once again! I couldn't see where the matching was taking place. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you are both piping `df` into `filter` and specifying it inside `filter`. It will avoid the error if you change `filter(df, grepl(...` to `filter(grepl(...`.

```
df %>%
  group_by(sen) %>% 
  filter(grepl("TW3", ia_label))
```

To do this for the first `target_pos` value corresponding to a `trial == "deviant"` by group, do this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(sen) %>%
  filter(grepl(
    pattern = first(target_pos[trial == "deviant"]),
    x = ia_label
  ))
# # A tibble: 6 × 5
# # Groups:   sen [2]
#     sen trial      ppt ia_label   target_pos
#   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     
# 1     1 standard     1 jumped_TW3 0         
# 2     1 silence      2 jumped_TW3 0         
# 3     1 deviant      3 jumped_TW3 TW3       
# 4     2 standard     1 the_TW4    0         
# 5     2 silence      2 the_TW4    0         
# 6     2 deviant      3 the_TW4    TW4
```